# How Can I Add a Character in ng-style form in DIV?

Tags: angularjs

I have tried NG-STYLE and apparently it seems to be working.
However, I need to put the percentage character (%) after bringing the data from the CONTROLLER.

```
<div class="progress progress-mini">
  <div ng-style="{'width' : project.project_completion '%'}">
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I think I have put that % sign in a wrong way.

What could be the best practice to put a character after bring the data from the Controller?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You have used wrong concatenation:

```
<div class="progress progress-mini">
  <div ng-style="{'width' : project.project_completion+'%'}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! Hope this also helps the others. :)